# Running slime in spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs, slime

I just installed a fresh spacemacs, and I'm trying to get SLIME working, but for some reason the package won't remain installed.

After opening a new spacemacs

```
M-x package-install RET slime
```

This works fine and I'm able to `M-x slime` and evaulate my lisp code. However, when I close spacemacs and reopen it, slime is no longer there, and I must repeat these steps.

I suspect it is because spacemacs isn't looking in the right spot for the slime package, but I'm not too familiar with how this works.

Has anyone experienced this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to answer this one myself.

Since some spacemacs configuration seems to have been reseting or preventing a load containing slime, I decided to just git clone slime into a different directory outside of .emacs.d and do this:

```el
;; Setup load-path, autoloads and your lisp system
;; Not needed if you install SLIME via MELPA

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/slime")
(require 'slime-autoloads)
(setq inferior-lisp-program "/usr/bin/sbcl")
```

This seems to have solved my issue.